# Transfer json files from dropbox to SQL Server 2016 database tables

Tags: database, dropbox, sql-server-2016

I have a requirement to automatically copy/transfer `.json` files that are located on dropbox to a SQL Server 2016 database. How can this be done, code examples. I have SQL Server 2016 but I am new to all of this.

If the `.json` files are in dropbox can SQL Server get them, then parse them into the database automatically or do I need something to copy the files down from dropbox first, then import these files directly or first parse then to some format (e.g. .csv) to populate tables in the SQL Server database?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server cannot directly access dropbox account. However, if you synchronize dropbox on some local folder or network path that is accessible by SQL Server, you can use OPENROWSET to read file and parse content with OPENJSON, see example in:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/10/07/bulk-importing-json-files-into-sql-server/